# Css style checkbox when not checked with jQuery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want my checkbox to change label color if not checked once the submit button is click. I'm using jQuery validator. I don't want the label to show, I just want to change the I Accept change to red.

Validation

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
  required:"This field is required",
  email: "A valid email address is required"
});
```

Checkbox

```
<label for="cbx2">
   <input name="TermsCondition" type="checkbox" value="on" style="float:left;" class="required" id="cbx2">
   <strong>I Accept</strong>
</label>
```

Css

```
label.error {
    font: 0/0 a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest css hack to fix this using css selectors. Just add this to your css.

```css
  .checkbox.valid ~ strong {
color:#000!important;
}

input.error,  .checkbox.error  ~ strong{
    border: 1px dotted red!important;
  color:red!important;
}

label.error {     
  display: none!important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


 <script>
 $.validator.setDefaults({
  submitHandler: function() {
   alert("submitted!");
  }
 });

 $().ready(function() {


  // validate signup form on keyup and submit
  $("#signupForm").validate({
   rules: {
    firstname: "required",
    lastname: "required",
    username: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 2
    },
    password: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5
    },
    confirm_password: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5,
     equalTo: "#password"
    },
    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true
    },
    topic: {
     required: "#newsletter:checked",
     minlength: 2
    },
    agree: "required"
   },
   messages: {
    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
    username: {
     required: "Please enter a username",
     minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
    },
    password: {
     required: "Please provide a password",
     minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
    },
    confirm_password: {
     required: "Please provide a password",
     minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
     equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
    },
    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
    agree: "Please accept our policy",
    topic: "Please select at least 2 topics"
   }
  });

  // propose username by combining first- and lastname
  $("#username").focus(function() {
   var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
   var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
   if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
    this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
   }
  });

  
  
 });
 </script>
 


<div id="main">
 

 <form class="cmxform" id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Validate a complete form</legend>
   <p>
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="confirm_password">Confirm password</label>
    <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="agree">Please agree to our policy</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree">
              <strong>I Accept</strong>
   </p>
  
  
   <p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </p>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please vote this if it solves your problem the easiest way.

Comment: @ Ani Menon it's working as expected. Check the added snippet.

Comment: The code is not working. I was able to do it on a simple input. But I wasn't able to do it in a checkbox.

Comment: Just added checkbox. heck the updated answer. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` `:not()` with parameter `:checked`, adjacent sibling `+` selector; at `onsubmit` event, if `#cbx2` is not `checked`, add `className` which sets `#cbx2` `color` to `red`

```js
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(event) {
  var message = this.querySelector("#cbx2");
  if (!message.checked) message.className = "invalid";
}
```

```css
#cbx2:not(:checked).invalid + strong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="cbx2">
    <input name="TermsCondition" type="checkbox" value="on" style="float:left;" class="required" id="cbx2">
    <strong>I Accept</strong>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I want it to turn red upon clicking the submit button.

Comment: @Jerika  _"I want it to turn red upon clicking the submit button."_ See updated post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Jquery validate **Callback Functions*** *( on success, on showErrors )* :

```js
$("#registerForm").validate({
  success: function() {
    $("#L_Accept").css('color', 'black');
  },
  showErrors: function() {
    $("#L_Accept").css('color', 'red');
    this.defaultShowErrors();
  },
  
  /* Disable (focusout, keyup, click) Events
     to force check validation by Submit Button ONLY.
  */
  onfocusout: false,
  onkeyup: false,
  onclick: false
});
```

```css
label.error {
  display:none !important; //hide default error label.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<h1>Form Validation Example</h1>
<form id='registerForm' name='registerForm' method='post' action='' >
  <label for="cbx2">
    <input name="TermsCondition" type="checkbox" value="on" style="float:left;" class="required" id="cbx2">
    <strong id="L_Accept">I Accept</strong>
  </label>
  
  <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: I want it to turn red once the submit button is submitted.

Comment: @Jerika See my updated answer, i hope it works as you want, Thanks